# It won't work when using media query to increase the size of the height of my body container when window size reduces.

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

I am trying to create a body container which takes up the whole space on my desktop screen which is what I want. However, when I resize it to the mobile screen, I want it to be responsive. It only takes up the quarter of space on a mobile screen. I also don't want my footer container and body container to overlap. I can fix it with overflow: auto. However, I don't want that to be the case. I don't want a user to scroll through my body, but rather static. Prefer my container to stick at the bottom. Here is the screenshot and my code:

**HTML**

```
<div class="header-container">
        <i class="fa fa-space-shuttle fa-spinner fa-spin fa-3x"></i>
    </div><br>


    <div class="body-container">
        <h1 class="body-title">The Mihir Chronicles</h1><br>
        <div class="body-content">
        <p>Hi, I am Mihir (me-here). I am a <strong>full-stack web developer</strong> and an entrepreneur based in Chicago. Previously, founded a social enterprise venture, <strong>Humble Pen</strong> and co-founded Royal Ace Investments.</p>

        <p>Aside from my entrepreneurial endeavours, I’ve also worked for several venture-backed startups. Currently, I am a mentor at Dev Mountain. Lately, I've been fascinated by programming. Usually, I am on my computer learning new frameworks and technologies.</p>

        <p>I am absolutely passionate about <strong>finance, programming</strong> and <strong>technology</strong>. I find <strong>art</strong> and <strong>astronomy</strong> to be absolutely cool. On the weekends, I volunteer as a <strong>Telescope Instructor</strong> at the Adler Planetarium. I usually read a lot when I am not working.</p>
        </div>
        <h2 class="body-end">-Mihir (me-here!)</h2>
        <a href="http://themihirchronicles.tumblr.com"><button class ="btn" type="text">Enter!</button></a>
        <!-- <button class ="btn" type="text">Essays</button> -->
    </div><br>

    <div class="footer-container">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="https://github.com/mihirchronicles"><i class="fa fa-github fa-2x"></i></a></li>
            <li><a href="https://twitter.com/mihirchronicles"><i class="fa fa-twitter fa-2x"></i></a></li>
            <li><a href="https://instagram.com/mihirchronicles"><i class="fa fa-instagram fa-2x"></i></a></li>
            <li><a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/mihirchronicles"><i class="fa fa-linkedin fa-2x"></i></a></li>
            <li><a href="mailto:mihirptl89@gmail.com"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o fa-2x"></i></a></li>
            <li><a href="http://themihirchronicles.tumblr.com/"><i class="fa fa-rss fa-2x"></i></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
* {box-sizing: border-box;}
 html, body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
 }

.header-container {
    color: #2789e5;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: justify;
    height: 15%;
    width: 85%;
    padding-top: 25px;
}

.body-container {
    margin: auto;
    text-align: left;
    height: 60%;
    width: 85%;
    font-family: serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  /*overflow: auto;*/
  border: dotted;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.footer-container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: right;
  width: 85%;
  height: 10%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  border: dotted;
}

.body-title {
    font-family: 'Reenie Beanie', cursive;
}

.body-content {
    font-family: "Courier New", Courier, monospace;
}

.body-end {
    font-family: 'Reenie Beanie', cursive;

}

ul li {
 list-style-type: none;
 float: left;
}
a {
    color: #70a2d1;
}

ul li a i:hover {
 opacity: .8;
}

li {
    margin: 0 0 0 15px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 300px) {
  .body-container {
    font-size: 1.5em;
  }
}
```

**ScreenShot for mobile screen**
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
```

Is what i think you mean.
Place it in your

```
<head>
```

part, and try hope it works for you.

With media querys i cant help you because i hate them.

```
overflow-x:hidden;
overflow-y:auto;
```

Comment: Change the overflow to overflow-x:hidden and overflow-y:auto.

Comment: Thank you, that works! Anyway, I can show the static content rather than user scroll through?

Comment: Well in most cases i came against this is an easier way to fix it, but still learning to work with the media query you asked for is a different story. I hope some people can maybe (if they want explane how its uses in a easy way), the meta tag will be ignored by browsers on computers like laptops and desktop pc's but mobile devices do know what its for.